# Django DRF - nested serializer (level>2) does not show up in the response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have the follwing structure `(library->books->pages)`

the first serializer

```
   class Library(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         books = BookSerializer(many=True)

         class Meta:
            model = Library
            fields = '__all__'

         @transaction.atomic
         def create(self, validated_data):
             # create logic here
```

the second serializer

```
   class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         pages = PageSerializer(many=True, required=False)

         class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = '__all__'
```

we have an endpoint  `library/`, where we post the payload of the following format

```
{
    "ref": "43a0c953-1380-43dd-a844-bbb97a325586",
    "books": [
        {
            "name": "The Jungle Book",
            "author": "Rudyard Kipling",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "content": "...",
                    "pagenumber": 22
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

all the objects are created in the database, but the response does not contain `pages` key. It looks like this

```
{
    "id": 27,
    "ref": "43a0c953-1380-43dd-a844-bbb97a325586",
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 34,
            "name": "The Jungle Book",
            "author": "Rudyard Kipling"
        }
    ]
}
```

`depth` attribute does not seem to work. What do I have to do to make `pages` appear in the responce?

Comment: You are sending `pages` attribute in request body, but in the serializer you are addressing it as `results` attribute, is it intended? And did you make sure the `pages` objects are actually created in database?

Comment: It was just misprint. I have edited it.

Comment: can u share ur models as well?

Comment: Post your model too

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the desired behavior using `depth` in the `class Meta` of the `BookSerializer`.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

...

   class Meta:
     ...
     depth = 3
```

Copied from [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)

> The `depth` option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.

Another way to get this behavior would be to use `serializer.SerializerMethodField` for getting the `pages` of the book serializer.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  pages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_pages(self, obj):
     return PageSerializer(obj.page_set.all(), many=True,).data

  ...
```